# How to restrict user to go to restricted page after log-out

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the requirement that the end user should not be able to go back to the restricted page after logout/signout. But currently the end user is able to do that by the browser back button.How can I achieve this the best?I am using Spring mvc.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Are you using `<cache-control/>` in Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the user getting back using browser history . you  could use this line in the jsp page.
window.history.forward(); 
hope you find it useful

Comment: But this is creating a flash effect means the previos page will blink and it wont shift .it doesnt look good can we have any other solution.